Pre-1990 movie where a man sees his leg cut off
Many years ago, when I would guess I was about five years old, I was being babysat by the church pastor's son while my parents were out at an event. I have one memory: he was watching a film and there was a disturbing scene. It was a movie he wanted to watch. I don't know if this means it was a famous movie, or just one that looked interesting according to the TV guide. This was in Australia, and we had only about four channels, but at least one (SBS) used to show "interesting" movies regularly.
I remember a man have the lower part of his leg cut off. I do not remember any cutting machinery, only the leg being sliced.  It slowly 'bent' away, and I recall seeing the cross-section of the remaining leg with a circular area being the bone visible among the circular cross-section leg flesh. In my memory, this was slow and mostly silent with the man watching it leave his body.  The scene background was white, or a dark blue / steel with lights. I recall, although I was five and horrified, that it occurred quite slowly. It is possible this was a science fiction film.
Date: probably before about 1990, definitely before 1995.

There are probably hundreds of movies that fit this description. My guess for a very popular movie from around that time would be Glory, the Civil War epic from 1989. There is a scene that matches you description in the first segment of the movie.

Whoop whoop, Straya!

Also, SBS tends to play many foreign films, was this an Australian, American, English or foreign film?

@BenPlont TA civil war epic does't sound sci-fi, but thankyou. Möoz, no idea.  I was about six!

Pity this is on hold. There's lots of detail: a specific scene, described action, who was on-screen, colours an background, music/silence, and a cutoff date. Honestly, I think that's quite good for a memory from when I was five or six years old.  The scene was a tad traumatic for me, as you can tell by still remembering it, and it would be nice to identify.
